# Can unrendered react components be seen by users in any way?

Tags: reactjs

Suppose we have a route with an option of displaying either a protected resource if the user is signed in otherwise public resources.

I do not render the protected resources until the user is signed in but can the user view the protected resource even though the component is not rendered as the application loads the data of that protected component as well.
So can that data be seen?

What will be the case if we have hooked up a node server with react and what if we have just deployed the react app without any backend?

clarification: this is just an attempt to understand the actual working of react production builds

Comment: Everything that is in your front-end javascript code and everything that was fetched from the server has to be considered public to the user. If you have private sensitive data that require permissions make sure you **authenticate the user first** and only then fetch any private data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never send protected resource along with the client. Though it is not rendered, all the data that is sent can be read. You can just open up your chrome dev tools and read the code. Anything and everything that is sent to the browser can be read.

Protected data should be stored in the backend, and every time the user requests for the data you need to authenticate. That is done usually by something called JWTs, and other methods. How it works is, the user when he sends to the server the username and password, the server verifies that they match and send back and token. Each subsequent request for protected data will carry along with it the token, so that you know that, that user was verified.

Read [this](https://jwt.io/introduction/) for more on JWTs.

Answer (score -1):

You should imagine that the code talking to your server isn't your javascript. If you're making unauthenticated API requests than anyone can write the code to hit your api and get a response, they can even use your code as a template to get them started.

Specifically to answer your question, unless something gets rendered it doesn't appear in the DOM so it won't be visible. For example if you were to pass a component as a child `<Example> <div>FIND ME</div> </Example>` and then never call the child like so `<div>Inner Example </div>` then if you checked the DOM there wouldn't be a `<div>FIND ME</div>`